# How to implement a notificator with pushbullet api?

Tags: c++, pushbullet

as in title I want to create a c++ programm and I want to include a notification system. I use pushbullet for all my devices so I decided to use the api. But the only manual I found is for html and php. 
I just want a simple way of implementing it. I found an incomplete libary for pushbullet. But is there a fully funktional lib I can use? Or is there a way without a lib (which I would go for).

Comment: Can't you simply send http request from C++ using your access token ?

Comment: @Clonk I'll try that thanks^^